# Git merge pulls extra items into merge target branch

Tags: git, visual-studio, merge, visual-studio-2019, team-explorer

I have a smallish 'feature' branch, call it `Quality`, and a main branch called `dev`. I sometimes want to  merge `dev` back into `Quality`, so that the differences between `dev` and `feature` remain minimal before it is time to merge `Quality` back into `dev` when I am done with `Quality`.

However, if I try a merge from `dev` back into `Quality` using VS 2019 Team Explorer, the merge seems to pull ever every artifact in `dev` that isn't in `Quality`, so my merge commit is full of hundreds of *Add*s. Can this be avoided in Team Explorer? I would prefer to keep a visual merge rather than a Git command line merge that just marks conflicts with little arrows.

Comment: What do you mean by *artefacts*? Back merge does what it had been asked for, i.e. takes everything in `dev` and applies it on top of `Quality`. Also, consider to use `git pull --rebase ... dev` (change `...` to your remote name) instead.

Comment: @0andriy I mean all kinds of files, not just source. I would have expected a back merge to only pull files that are in the target branch from the source branch. I will try what you suggest, thanks.

Comment: Git doesn't touch files that are outside of its scope. So, if you see *garbage* after merge it means that `dev` branch **contains** it. Also you may try `git clean -xdf` (It's dangerous operation, it will clean everything in the current folder which is not in the Git index!)

Comment: @0andriy Thanks for the input. What will `git pull --rebase ... dev` do though?

Comment: It will keep your topic branch clean and always fast forward against master.